# Nuances of when the word "once" should/shouldn't be used as a conjunction (referring to single events vs. an interval after a a starting point)

Tags: conjunctions, connotation

I have a coworker who is a non-native English speaker (not that this matters... sometimes he corrects my errors!) and used the word *once* in a way that seemed awkward to me. It was something like the following:

> Once the calibration procedure starts, it will make a set of measurements and perform statistical analysis.

The leading clause *Once the calibration procedure starts* is fine, but it didn't seem to fit with the rest of the sentence. And I gave him the following reply, but I'm not 100% sure about it and can't find reference information to confirm:

> “once” doesn’t quite seem right here... it is usually used for a prolonged condition rather than an event, e.g. “once the President is elected, there is no way to unelect him except through the impeachment procedure” rather than “once the President is elected, he will appoint cabinet members”.

Am I correct, or is *once* (when used as a conjunction) just a synonym for *after* (or *as soon as*, per @deadrat's comment)?

Comment: It's a synonym for *as soon as*.

Comment: His sentence is fine. Google "Once the timer starts" and see how many hits you get.

Comment: medica, you might be missing my point, "Once the calibration starts" as a clause is fine, but there is a nuance to what it means. "Once the timer starts, the dialog box will be updated several times per second" is fine. "Once the timer starts, the dialog box will be closed" sounds odd to me, because it's a single event.

Comment: If I were copyediting the sentence, I would remove the entire "Once the calibration procedure starts" clause and replace "it" with "The calibration procedure." I would do the same thing if the opening clause were "After the calibration procedure starts" or "When the calibration procedure starts." My reason is not that the sentence is unclear with any of those introductory phrases in place, but that explaining what the procedure does doesn't require specifying that first it has to start. But this is a matter of effective writing style, not of fundamental coherence.

Comment: ...Also, to avoid any implication that the procedure occurs automatically if left to its own devices, I might recast the sentence in simple present tense: "The calibration procedure makes a set of measurements and performs statistical analysis."

Comment: The sentence seems ok to me.